# Multiple values in one parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure needs to insert multiple products in the [Order Details] table.

One OrderID = Many products.

I saw a code where you will create a temporary table like a list to store multiple values. But I don't know how to use it when the values is not pre-defined or is a user input.

```
--I want to input multiple ProductID in this temporary table
DECLARE @myOrders table (ID int)
INSERT INTO @myOrders ("")
--Then get data from the Products table and input the data in Order Details
INSERT INTO [Order Details] (ProductID)
SELECT ProductID From Products
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ID FROM @myOrders)
```

Sample pic of Order details

[image]

Comment: "the values is not pre-defined or is a user input." what do you mean by this? Your Order Details table have a fixed structure, you only need to pass multiple rows for fixed columns, or you are expecting something else?

Comment: it is good  if you share some code

Comment: I have posted some code @kakabali

Comment: Unless your table allows it (and I hope not) you can't just insert product IDs to order table. Where's your orderID, quantities etc?

Comment: @PSK, when I execute the stored procedure in sql server, I must be able to input multiple ProductID.

Comment: @JamesZ, I didn't send my whole code but the Order table contains the OrderID and I used scope_identity so that I can use it for [Order Details] table. I need to be able to input multiple productId and store it inside the temp table myOrders. There is another table that contains the ProductID and UnitPrice.

Comment: You can pass a table variable to a stored procedure, containing all the data.

Comment: @PSK, but how am I going to input multiple ProductID when I execute the stored procedure? That will able to pass all the parameters of that multiple ProductID. From Products table to Order Details table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define type like following

```
CREATE TYPE ProductList AS TABLE
(
        ProductId INT  
)
GO
```

Then create your procedure like following

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_TEST_PROC (@OrderId INT,@Produt_Id_List ProductList READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @OrderDetails TABLE(OrderId INT, ProductID INT,UnitPrice DECIMAL(18,2),Quantity INT, Discount DECIMAL(18,2))

    DECLARE @Products TABLE(ProductID INT,UnitPrice DECIMAL(18,2),Quantity INT, Discount DECIMAL(18,2))

    INSERT INTO @OrderDetails (OrderId, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity, Discount)
    SELECT @OrderId, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount FROM @Products WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductId FROM @Produt_Id_List)

    SELECT * FROM @OrderDetails
END
```

Then prepare table variable to put values like following

```
DECLARE @PList ProductList;
INSERT @PList VALUES (1),(2),(3)
```

Finally call procedure

```
EXEC USP_TEST_PROC 100,@PList
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks! If I'm going to put values when I execute it, can I write this "EXEC USP_TEST_PROC 10,15,20,40?'" Can I put multiple values at the same time?

Comment: can I define the type table within the same stored proc?

Comment: You need to create table type outside the procedure. It only needs to be created once, and used anytime. Thanks.

Comment: @Nivram, you need to prepare table type by inserting value. then you can call procedure to provide that table type parameter. Can you please mention your exact need.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures accept table inputs in the form of table values parameters. Look at the documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

This includes an example also on how to invoke such a stored procedure.

You can directly use the TVP similar to a table variable (@myOrders in you sample) in the stored procedure body.

If you are looking to also call that stored procedure from ADO.NET, below article has a good description.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters

Comment: Do you know the exact code if the parameter's values will be entered by the user? All the examples that I saw already have values.

Comment: Are you looking for an example on how to call the stored procedure which uses a TVP parameter? If so, where is the call made from? T-SQL or C# or some place else. From T-SQL you can populate multiple rows into the TVP using normal INSERT statements

Comment: I created a TVP parameter, I don't know how to receive values when executing. Will this work?
DECLARE @myList ProductList

Comment: INSERT @myOrders
VALUES (1),(2)

What if it's more than 2 values?